# Out of which alloys are the Common Core Booster and Common Booster Core propellent tanks manufactured?

Tags: materials, ula, atlas-v, delta-iv

All sources that I can find indicate that they are isogrid (or possibly orthogrid?) structural tanks manufactured of milled aluminum. However, I cannot find further detail about of which alloy *specifically* they are composed.

Are they Al-Li 2198, as is Falcon 9, or are they more similar to the Apollo-era Al 2014 used on upper stages of the Saturn family?

(Despite one being kerolox and one being hydrolox, I assume ULA makes their two booster families out of the same material to simplify logistics. I may be very wrong about that!)

Comment: I thought it was a typo, but nope! [Common Core Booster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Core_Booster) and [Common Booster Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Booster_Core)

Comment: An alloy suitable for the temperature of LOX may be too brittle at the temperature of LH2.

Comment: In both cases they use Al 2014.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: For Atlas V:https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/rockets/atlasvusersguide2010.pdf page 375 For Delta IV you should explore FSW techniques of welding

Comment: To make it easier for you:https://books.google.rs/books?id=JW2l2L-UYS4C&pg=PA297&lpg=PA297&dq=FSW+2014+welding+on+Delta&source=bl&ots=_mlL6WB09r&sig=ACfU3U2t47IuHpFoGoTpVbzljqKyhySCiw&hl=sr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMhrCLscrnAhWzD2MBHW5qB0QQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=FSW%202014%20welding%20on%20Delta&f=false chapter 13.4

Comment: Put this together as an answer, and you have the bounty.

Comment: Tnx but i don't need it.